# Why are default methods not allowed in annotation types in Java 8?

Tags: java, interface, annotations, java-8

I today saw a glimpse of the wonderful world of annotations, so I tried my own code, but it does not want to compile:

```
public @interface SomeAnnotation {
    public String sayHello1() default "Hello world";

    default public String sayHello2() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

What you see in `sayHello1`, is how default arguments for annotations are to be specified.
What I am wondering though, is why `sayHello2` is not allowed, which is available since Java 8.

To me it seems to be providing the same functionality, or am I missing something here?

Also, why did annotations have access to default method bodies (albeit very simple ones) since Java 5, while interfaces had to wait until Java 8?

Comment: `What I am wondering though, is why sayHello2 is not allowed since Java 8.` I jave JDK7 and my compiler says `default methods are not supported in -source 1.7
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable default methods)`

Comment: Annotations don't have default method bodies. They only have default values. They are, essentially, properties. Default method bodies in interfaces allow interfaces to evolve after they are published, and provide a form of multiple inheritance of behavior (traits).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This

```
public String sayHello1() default "Hello world";
```

is providing the default value of the annotation element. That is, if you didn't provide it in the annotation, that's the value it would have. [From the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6)

> The body of an annotation type may contain method declarations, **each
>   of which defines an element of the annotation type.** An annotation type
>   has no elements other than those defined by the methods it explicitly
>   declares.

and

> An annotation type element may have a default value, specified by
>   following the element's (empty) parameter list with the keyword
>   `default` and an `ElementValue` (§9.7.1).

So

```
@SomeAnnotation // sayHello1 would have value "Hello world"
public class Foo {}
```

and

```
@SomeAnnotation(sayHello1 = "other value") // sayHello1 would have value "other value"
public class Foo {}
```

Then

```
SomeAnnotation ann = ...;
String value = ann.sayHello1();
```

If you don't provide a `default` value, then you must provide a value when annotating something.

This

```
default public String sayHello2() {
    return "Hello world";
}
```

is the syntax for a `default` method in an `interface` since Java 8. You can execute anything in this method. **That is not true for an annotation which only provides metadata, not behavior.**

> Also, why did annotations have access to default method bodies (albeit
>   very simple ones) since Java 5, while interfaces had to wait until
>   Java 8?

**They didn't. The two things above are completely different.**